# CipherOutputStream and FileOutputStream(someFile, true) results in garbage when appending data

Tags: java, android, filestream, aes, cryptography

I'm encrypting data on Android with a CipherOutputStream through a BufferedOutputStream to a FileOutputStream(someFile, true). I use the "AES/CBC/NoPadding" for the cipher settings. Currently constant IV and key. I decrypt the data on the Mac. Encoding and decoding works well in this setting.

But when i reopen the encrypted file and append encrypted data I get garbaged data at the beginning of the appended data section. Could this be a problem of some sort of minimum block size for encrypting data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"CBC" stands for "chained block cipher". What this means is that the content is chopped up into fixed-size blocks, and each block is encrypted, but the encrypted form of a block *is dependent on all the blocks that came before it*.

For a given block number i, the cipher text c_i is derived from the plaintext block p_i as follows: `c_i = encrypt(p_i xor c_i-1)`. (For the first block, you xor with the IV).

Lets say you encrypt three blocks, you get c_1, c_2, and c_3. If you wanted to append a fourth block to that, c_4 should be equal to `encrypt(p_4 xor c_3)`, but what you are actually adding is `encrypt(p_4 xor IV)`.

What you need to add is `encrypt(p_4 xor c_3)`, you should recover the last encrypted block in the file and use it as the IV for the first appended block. That should then work fine.

*However,* we haven't discussed the problem of padding. If your data isn't exactly divisible into blocks, the final block will have some padding at the end. To properly store the data, you should decrypt the final block (which would be a simple block decode using your key, and the cipher text of the penultimate block instead of the IV) and remove it from the file. Prefix your new data with this decrypted block, and then do your append as above.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer and solution to the padding problem! I will try this out.

Comment: It might be easier to devise a way to be able to remove padding from the middle of the message so you can just append, rather than delete + append. This might open you up to subtle padding attacks though (emphasis on the might, this is beyond my knowledge)

Comment: From a cryptographically secure standpoint, I don't know which is better. Perhaps a new question on that topic? :P I would probably do it how I said in the post, rather than leaving the padding in.

Answer (score 1):

When you append, are you creating a new `Cipher` instance, and initializing it with the IV that you started with when you created the file? That won't work.

If you create a new `Cipher` instance for appending, you'll need to set its IV to be the last block of cipher text in the file.

In CBC, the previous cipher text block is XOR'd with the plain text before encryption. At the beginning of the file, there is no "previous cipher text block", so you make one up: the IV. But all subsequent blocks have a previous block, and you need to use it as "the IV" if you append data mid-stream.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I simply ignored the fact that the initial IV is used again when appending data to the file.